# Calculate difference between rows and keep the first row always 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I have to calculate the difference between row values in Table X (SQL Server)

Table X

```
ID  A 
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
```

So I wrote the following SQL query

```
SELECT ID,
       A
       A - COALESCE (lag(A) OVER (ORDER BY date), 0) AS Difference
FROM Table X
```

And the result is

```
ID  A    Difference
1   100   100
2   200  -100
3   300  -100
4   400  -100
```

What I want is to keep the first-row Difference always as 0

```
ID  A    Difference
1   100   0
2   200  -100
3   300  -100
4   400  -100
```

But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Just wrap the whole difference expression `A - lag(A)... ` inside the `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to pass а value for the `default` parameter of the `LAG()` window function. As is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments), the `default` parameter is the *value to return when offset is beyond the scope of the partition* (and for the first row, the previous row is beyond that scope).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (ID int, A int, [Date] date)
INSERT INTO Data (ID, A, [Date]) 
VALUES 
  (1, 100, '20200701'), 
  (2, 200, '20200702'), 
  (3, 300, '20200703'), 
  (4, 400, '20200704')
```

Statment:

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   A,
   LAG(A, 1, A) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) - A AS Difference
FROM Data
```

Result:

```
ID  A   Difference
------------------
1   100 0
2   200 -100
3   300 -100
4   400 -100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following query.

For this type of query `order by` clause is important based on the column and the applied `order by` clause `ascending` or `descending` the result can be different.

```
create table Test(ID int,
A int)

insert into Test values
(1,   100),
(2,   200),
(3,   300),
(4,   400)

SELECT ID
,A
,Difference
FROM (
SELECT ID
    ,A
    ,isnull(A - LAG(A) OVER (
            ORDER BY A DESC
            ), 0) Difference
FROM test
) t
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a5a2357b67496722756ef87b57fae3f9)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @zhorov for the table schema, data

You can use ISNULL or COALESCE to arrive at the difference.

```sql
DECLARE @Data table(ID int, A int, [Date] date)
INSERT INTO @Data (ID, A, [Date]) 
VALUES 
  (1, 100, '20200701'), 
  (2, 200, '20200702'), 
  (3, 300, '20200703'), 
  (4, 400, '20200704')

  SELECT ID,A, ISNULL(LAG(A,1) OVER(ORDER BY DATE),A) AS difference FROM @Data
--or you can use COALESCE
  SELECT ID,A, COALESCE(LAG(A,1) OVER(ORDER BY DATE),A) AS difference FROM @Data
```

```
+----+-----+------------+
| ID |  A  | difference |
+----+-----+------------+
|  1 | 100 |        100 |
|  2 | 200 |        100 |
|  3 | 300 |        200 |
|  4 | 400 |        300 |
+----+-----+------------+
```